# Validation on server vs. validation on device

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm currently trying to get the hang of in-app purchases on Android. I want to implement a non-consumable one-time product, i.e. allow perpetual access to all content in the app after purchasing the product.

In the Android developer guide for In-App-Billing there is a "Best practices" section (see https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices ).

It states: *"It's highly recommended to validate purchase details on a server that you trust. [...] By implementing your signature verification logic on a server, you make it difficult for attackers to reverse-engineer your APK file."*

I do not understand the logic behind this claim - assuming one does not have user accounts in the app.

Both methods seem to implement a signature check - either on the device or on a remote server.

I guess that the cracking tools that are available are able to scan for and disable the on device security check - so maybe this is meant by "making it difficult".

Otherwise I don't see a difference whether a reverse-engineer looks for the on-device check vs. looking for the server-roundtrip. Both calls can be be removed or replaced by an "always true" return value.

The best practices document also states: *"verify that the orderId is a unique value that you have not previously processed"*.
Even this seems questionable to (for?) me.

Assuming that the reverse engineer is not able to find and replace the verification round-trip to the server and you keep track of all order ids on a remote server - they still are not tied to any user id. So how can you decide, whether

- a user has switched devices (or lost his data) and is restoring purchases or
- someone tries to gain access to paid content illegitimately?

(I guess you could check via heuristics - say allow 3 same order ids in X months, but there would always be the risk of blocking legitimate buyers.)

These questions appear to be rather basic to me - therefore I assume that I'm simply not getting the whole picture. I would be very thankful, if someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: The signature cannot be guessed. So a check server-side is always preferable because it's on your control and given that the signature was not spoofed, it can easily be detected as legit server-side. That with a combinaison of AndroidId should provide sufficent security.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm with you that a signature check in an environment controlled by the programmer is preferrable. I'm arguing that the difficulty for a reverse engineer to remove the on-device check is no different from removing a https call to the server-side. So at the moment I see no merit in the claim of the best practices document, that server side signature verification will make it difficult for attackers to reverse-engineer the APK.

Comment: I would tend to think about the code from an APK that can expose a lot of logic and salts and what not. Reverse-engineer a sniffed (http) stream of data is much harder because it's hashed and appears obfuscated. Bytecode or even recompiled Java code is so much easier to replicate.

Comment: That is not how I see it - a reverse engineer would investigate the (obfuscated) code to find the place where a purchase is made and insert some replayed data instead of a real Google Play answer. He would then continue to examine the code and would end up at some call like https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive_v2/shared-module/src/main/java/com/example/billingmodule/billing/Security.java line 94. From my point of view there is no difference whether the Security class does local verification or starts a HTTP(S) call - you would simply replace the call.

Comment: Thus no sniffing of HTTP streams would be necessary.

Comment: That's a valid point. Not sure if you'll find your answer on SO but upvoted.